# HTML BG image not showing

Tags: html

so I literally just copied and pasted this code from another directory of my site, css and all, and the BG image is not showing. It just shows as white. I made sure to recreate the images folder in the new directory and reupload the background, but the background just doesnt show. Here is my CSS (with the bg image)

```
html,body {
    background: url(images/bg_body.png) ;
    font-family:Capriola;
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<html>
<style>
html,body {
    background: url(images/bg_body.png) ;
    font-family:Capriola;
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
}


</style>
<head>
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="images/styles.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <title>SeaJay Source</title>


</head>
<body>
<body>
<center><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<img src="assets/logo.png" />
<div id="posting" class="posting">
<div class="title" id="title" color="white">Login</div>
<div id="texts" class="texts">
Welcome to SeaJay Source!<br>
<form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" >
Username: <input class="input" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" /><br>
Password: <input class="input" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" /><br>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Login" /> <br>
</form>

</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I tried to include the styling inside the html file also, but that didn't work.

Comment: Did you at least try a full url to the `background`? Like, apparently, `background: url(http://skypeipresolver.servehttp.com/images/bg_body.png);`? Try your console NET tab, too, and see if the image is downloading or you're getting an error. You just have to troubleshoot, dude.

Comment: Also, `<center><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>` breaks my heart. `center` is deprecated, and please, please don't use `br` tags to create whitespace, use `padding-top` or `margin-top` on the `body` or wrapping element.

Comment: `<center` is deprecated, consider using `margin` or `padding` (instead of *lots* of `br` elements). Consider using `background-image` for your `background-image` (rather than the shorthand `background` property, if you're only setting *one property*).

Comment: @JaredFarrish It works with the full url, and no that is not my domain. But why does it work with the full url and not the directory?

Comment: I don't know; really, you just need to inspect the `body` element and try to determine what the actual full URL is that the `body` tag is using to set the background with. Chrome and Firefox Firebug both allow you to do this; you should learn how to do it, it's really, really useful for this kind of thing.

Comment: Omg that was it... My styles.css is inside of the images folder already so It was trying to access  http://domain.com/dir/images/images/blue.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> from another directory

That's your problem, almost certainly.

Always specify URLs relative to the root of your domain. It should look like `url('/path/to/image.png')`

URLs in CSS can be confusing, since some thing use the HTML file's location as a base, and others use the CSS file's location. It's just easier all around to specify your URLs relative to a fixed base: the root.

Comment: the thing is, I will be distributing this source, so the paths will be different, I have NO idea why just images/bg.png doesnt work it works fine in my other folder. And there are 2 images folders, one in each directory, so It should be accessible. <body background"images/bg.png> works...